# Eigenvalues of three anti diagonal Hankel matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, hankel-matrices

Is there a way to obtain eigenvalues of  three anti-diagonal $n \times n$ Hankel matrix
$$
H=\left(                                                                                               \begin{array}{ccccc}                                                                                                 L & 0& ... & 0& b& c \\  
0 & 0& ... & b& c& d \\
0 & 0& ... & c& d& 0 \\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots  \\
b&c&d&...&0&0\\
c&d&0&...&0&L\\                                                                                                                                                                         \end{array}                                                                                             \right)
$$
in closed form?

Is it possible in the case $L=0$?
In my specific case $a,b,c$ are imaginary and $L$ is real.

I can do it for a specific case $b=d$ by noticing that eigenvalues are the same (up to complex conjugation) as in Toeplitz matrix
$$
H=\left(                                                                                               \begin{array}{ccccc}                                                                                                 L+c & b& 0&\dots      \\
b&c&b&\dots\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots\\
\dots & 0&b & c+L                                                                                                                                                            \end{array}                                                                                             \right)
$$
for which formula is given in https://www.emis.de/journals/AMEN/2005/040903-7.pdf.

Comment: The matrix is almost a circulant matrix which would have a basis of complex exponentials as eigenvectors and the FFT of the most commonly occurring row vector as eigenvalues. Maybe that can help.